# Get uniqueId() of cloned element

Tags: jquery

I am assigning a unique `id` to a cloned `div` using [uniqueId()](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/).

I want to get this unique `id` and set it to a `data` attribute`.

```
jQuery(data).clone().uniqueId().show().appendTo('body');
```

Comment: What does `uniqueId` return? Is that a jQuery method? What is the problem?

Comment: it assign a ID called 'ui-id-1` to my cloned element

Comment: You add a jquery UI reference if you're using it http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in that case you can try

```
var el = jQuery(data).clone().uniqueId().show().appendTo('body');
el.data('id', el.attr('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(data).clone()
            .uniqueId()
            .attr('data-id', function() {
               return this.id;
            }).show()
            .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: you trying to get id from `data-id`, but I said get cloned id and set it to `data-id`.

Comment: @HowToPlease from [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) doc `Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.`